# MySQL double entry when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a web application using PHP and MySQL the thing is, when I insert data into my table using PHP, double records of the entry are made into the table. I've isolated the insertion part, hence the `die();` at the bottom, but can't get it to work properly. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email1'];
$password = '12345';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tele = $_POST['tele'];
$registo = gmdate('Y-m-d', time());
$id_priv = 1;

$server     = 'localhost';
$baseDados  = 'dbase101';
$userName   = 'root';
$passWord   = '';

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $server . ';dbname=' . $baseDados . ';charset=utf8;', $userName, $passWord);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$insert = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (email, password, name, telephone, registry, id_priv) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$password."', '".$name."','".$tele."','".$registry."','".$id_priv."')";
$conn->exec($insert);
echo "New record created successfully";

die( );
```

*edit*
Taking your answers to consideration I did 2 things:
1 - I changed the code to bind the parameters correctly.
2 - I double checked how this file was being called. It turned out that I was using AJAX to submit the form using an external js file and had the same function written at the bottom of the file which contained the form, this way the form was being submitted twice.

```
const SERVIDOR = '127.0.0.1';
const BD = 'prime101';
const USER = 'root';
const PASS = '';

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SERVIDOR . ';dbname=' . DB . ';charset=utf8;', USER, PASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (email, password, nome_pessoa, telefone, registo, id_priv)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$insert = $conn->prepare($sql);
$insert->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(3, $nome_pessoa, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(4, $telefone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(5, $registo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(6, $id_priv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->execute();

echo "New record created successfully";

die;
```

I'd like to thank you all for your answers, it really helped me to rewrite the code and analyse the source of problem. 
I'd also like to apologize for my English, as it is not my first language, and for being a noob and asking this question.

Comment: could be a number of reasons; I know of a few, but I'd hate to guess till the cows came home. Want to know what they could be?

Comment: I suspect your form is posting twice.  Show how this file is called.  Also, don't use PDO if you're not going to bind your parameters correctly anyway.

Comment: it depends on many cases... can you share the flow...I mean from where this script is getting called...